# IPv6 multicast not working in LAN

Tags: c++, networking, ipv6, multicast

I tried to send an IPv6 multicast packet through my network. The sending seems to work, since it arrives on the destination PC - at least it appears in the logged network traffic in WireShark. But it does not arrive in my server program. When I send a packet from the same PC that should receive it, it does work though.

This is the code for sending (removed error checking for better readability):

```
UDPBroadcastSocket = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
BOOL Yes = 1;
setsockopt(UDPBroadcastSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char*)&Yes, sizeof(BOOL));
int32_t hops = 50;
setsockopt(UDPBroadcastSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS, (char*)&hops, sizeof(hops));
uint32_t IF = 0;
setsockopt(UDPBroadcastSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, (char*)&IF, sizeof(IF));

struct sockaddr_in6 sock_in;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;

getaddrinfo("FF18::1243", "12346", &hints, &result);

unsigned char buffer[MAXBUF];
int PacketSize = 8;
int sinlen = int(result->ai_addrlen);
memcpy(&sock_in, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);

freeaddrinfo(result);

sendto(UDPBroadcastSocket, (char*)buffer, PacketSize, 0, (sockaddr *)&sock_in, sinlen);
```

And this is the code for receiving the packet (removed error checking for better readability):

```
std::vector<uint32_t> GetNetworkInterfaceIndices(){
    std::vector<uint32_t> Result;

    /* Declare and initialize variables */

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    unsigned int i = 0;

    // Set the flags to pass to GetAdaptersAddresses
    ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX;

    // default to unspecified address family (both)
    ULONG family = AF_UNSPEC;

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = NULL;
    ULONG outBufLen = 0;
    ULONG Iterations = 0;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pUnicast = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS pAnycast = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS pMulticast = NULL;
    IP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS *pDnServer = NULL;
    IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX *pPrefix = NULL;



    family = AF_INET6;



    // Allocate a 15 KB buffer to start with.
    outBufLen = WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE;

    do {

        pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)MALLOC(outBufLen);
        if (pAddresses == NULL) {
            return{ 0 };
        }

        dwRetVal =
            GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

        if (dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
            FREE(pAddresses);
            pAddresses = NULL;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

        Iterations++;

    } while ((dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) && (Iterations < MAX_TRIES));

    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
        // If successful, output some information from the data we received
        pCurrAddresses = pAddresses;
        while (pCurrAddresses) {

            Result.emplace_back(pCurrAddresses->IfIndex);

            pCurrAddresses = pCurrAddresses->Next;
        }
    }
    else {

        return{ 0 };
    }

    if (pAddresses) {
        FREE(pAddresses);
    }

    return Result;
}



UDPSocket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

sockaddr_in6 UDP_Sock_in;
memset(&UDP_Sock_in, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));
UDP_Sock_in.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
UDP_Sock_in.sin6_port = htons(Settings::GetPort()+1);
UDP_Sock_in.sin6_family = PF_INET6;

setsockopt(UDPSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char*)&No, sizeof(BOOL));

bind(UDPSocket, (sockaddr*)&UDP_Sock_in, sizeof(UDP_Sock_in));

ipv6_mreq BroadcastGroup;

memset(&BroadcastGroup, 0, sizeof(ipv6_mreq));

const auto IfIndices = GetNetworkInterfaceIndices();

BroadcastGroup.ipv6mr_multiaddr.u.Byte[0] = 0xFF;
BroadcastGroup.ipv6mr_multiaddr.u.Byte[1] = 0x18;
BroadcastGroup.ipv6mr_multiaddr.u.Byte[14] = 0x12;
BroadcastGroup.ipv6mr_multiaddr.u.Byte[15] = 0x43;

for (const auto& Index : IfIndices) {
    BroadcastGroup.ipv6mr_interface = Index;
    setsockopt(UDPSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&BroadcastGroup, sizeof(ipv6_mreq));        
} 



socklen_t fromLength = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);

pollfd PollFd;
PollFd.events = POLLIN;
PollFd.fd = UDPSocket;
PollFd.revents = -1;

WSAPoll(&PollFd, 1, -1);

recvfrom(UDPSocket, (char*)buffer, MAXBUF, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromLength);
```

I basically tried specifying every single network interface index and the packet still does not arrive in the server. I have no idea what could be wrong. And why does it work when sender and receiver are on the same PC? I don't understand this. Does anyone have an idea? It's not the firewall, I turned it off and nothing changed. When I specify the IP address of the receiving PC directly, it does work, too.

Comment: C or C++? Please don't tag both languages unless you're actually programming in both. They are, after all, very different languages.

Comment: Check the return status of the functions you are using. No point in blindly guessing what the problem could be.

Comment: It's C++, I changed it, sorry. I actually check the return values, I just removed it for better readability in this post.

Comment: In my experience IPv6-multicast works better if you create a separate socket for each network interface, rather than trying to handle all of the network interfaces using a single socket.  (it's a pain to have to do that, of course)

Comment: Well, it doesn't work at all even if I only add the socket to one interface. I already tried that and a lot of other combinations of options. For some reason, it works with IPv4 without any problem at all. I still want to know if I did something wrong or it actually is a bug, but I guess I'll never find out.

Answer (score -3):

I found a workaround: Simply switch to IPv4, because IPv6 multicast currently doesn't seem to work on Windows (at least in my use case, see comments). My code had worked, but stopped working some time ago and I didn't notice until I tested it again.

I tried a bunch of different addresses and apparently none of them worked on 3 different devices. Then I switched to IPv4 and it simply worked - I changed only the IPv6 related stuff to their IPv4 equivalent and removed the hops and interface options on the sender.

My receiver even appeared in the multicast groups list (which you can see using the command "netsh interface ipv6 show joins"), but still didn't receive the packets sent to its address, so I concluded that it likely is a bug, since every example code I found did not work for me and I could not find any other option for setsockopt that I could have missed. Feel free to comment if you have any idea what might have caused this problem or how to fix it without switching back to the old IPv4 standard.

Comment: "_IPv6 multicast currently doesn't seem to work on Windows_" IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, so it heavily uses multicast. Windows could not use IPv6 if it did not support IPv6 multicast. For example, IPv4 uses ARP, which is broadcast, to discover the layer-2 address of other hosts on its LAN. Since IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, it uses multicast for neighbor discovery, and every IPv6 unicast or anycast address on an interface requires a corresponding solicited-node multicast address.

Comment: IPv6 Multicast NEEDS to work on Windows since its used as a replacement of Broadcast

Comment: Well, I know that it should work, but apparently it doesn't work for me for some reason. My receiver joined the multicast group on every single interface and still did not receive the packet sent to its multicast address, although it showed up in WireShark. I had to get this to work so I tried it for 5 hours, despite there being examples that are very easy. I tried a lot of combinations of options, none of it worked. I don't understand this. It worked for packets sent from the same PC, so the code likely was correct.

Comment: It might actually work with other applications like address discovery because they work on the kernel level or something, but I'm just guessing here. I just know that my previously working code stopped working although I definitely changed nothing. I'm still wondering why and I would be happy if anyone could tell me what I did wrong in the code given in the question. Maybe the documentation on MSDN is wrong (I actually found a thing that is not working as documented, so that may actually be a possibility).

Comment: Another possible cause for it not working may be that I create two TCP sockets for listening before I create the UDP socket and that somehow breaks the address mapping. (I try to discover servers running on the local network in the client.) I can rule out the firewall because I disabled it (both Windows Firewall and Windows Defender Firewall) and this didn't fix the problem. At least that use case may be so special (IPv6 multicast instead of IPv4 multicast in combination with detecting servers instead of clients) that such a bug, if present, may not have been found yet.